# How to move the cursor to the end of the line in ACE Editor?

Tags: javascript, html, ace-editor

Inside my Javascript file I have the following lines of code:

```
editor.focus(); // To focus the ace editor
var n = editor.getSession().getValue().split("\n").length - 2;
editor.gotoLine(n);
```

This focuses the ACE editor, moves to the last line, and goes up two lines. When it goes up those two lines it also moves the cursor to the front of that line. Simulating someone pressing the <kbd>Home</kbd> key.

**Q:** How do I move the cursor to the end of the line? Or simulate the <kbd>End</kbd> Key?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

`gotoline` takes two arguments one for row and one for column

```
var row = editor.session.getLength() - 1
var column = editor.session.getLine(row).length // or simply Infinity
editor.gotoLine(row + 1, column)
```

Note that `gotoLine` scrolls selection into view with an animation, If you do not want that you can use

```
editor.selection.moveTo(row, column)
```

instead.

To simulate the <kbd>end</kbd> key exactly the way it is handled when the user presses <kbd>end</kbd> use

```
editor.execCommand("gotolineend")
```

Comment: There's a typo in the first `gotoLine`. The other ones are spelled correctly.

Answer (score 8):

Straight from [API](http://ace.c9.io/#nav=api&api=editor):

[image: The method]

You want to use the method `navigateLineEnd()`. So in your case:

```
editor.focus(); // To focus the ace editor
var n = editor.getSession().getValue().split("\n").length - 2;
editor.gotoLine(n); 
editor.navigateLineEnd() // Navigate to end of line
```